# Cocos2d - Change CCNode Image Programmatically

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder, ccnode

Does anyone know how to change a CCNode's image programmatically? I'm using SpriteBuilder to make a simple game.

Comment: did you mean CCSprite?

Answer (score 2):

A CCNode does not have an image. Only CCSprites have images.
You can change the image of a CCSprite using the `spriteFrame` property.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a CCNode object in your scene, you'll need to create a method in the object's implementation file an call it out when you want to change the image.

**In the Scene code:**

```
CustomObject *blahblah;

[blahblah ChangeNodeImage:"FrameName.png"];
```

**In the CCNode implementation file:**

```
-(void) ChangeNodeImage: (NSString *) theImageFrameName;
{
    CCSpriteFrame* imageframe = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:theImageFrameName];
    [CustomObject setDisplayFrame:imageframe];        
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to change a background image, and the background was a CCNode. I'll let you know if I have any issues, when I go to try this later.